# Changed Domain name, now have 2 how to redirect to preferred one using htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress Site and a PHPBB forum on `/forums` sub-directory.

I added a new domain to the website in Apache. After adding the domain everything would load on both domains.

Then I changed the address on WP-config file, WP now automatically 301 redirects to the new domain (yes, [that's a thing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88742/does-wordpress-automatically-do-301-redirect-if-i-change-permalink)).

So far so good. `/forums/` Still loads on both new and old domain.
How can I redirect this sub-directory keeping in mind that both new and old domains are added to the same server installation? So when you visit with any domain all hit the same `.htaccess` file.

So I need something like Redirect **only `/forums/`** and only when it's accessed by old domain to new domain. Is that possible?

I can't remove the old domain from the site else it wouldn't resolve. I guess I could create a new site only to redirect but that seems unnecessary somehow.

**EDIT: My attempt (Not working)**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forums/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/forums/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to clarify, you want to redirect `old-domain.com/forums/<anything>` to `new-domain.com/forums/<anything>`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forums/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/forums/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

This will redirect to `https://new-domain.com/forums/forums/<whatever>`, since the `$1` backreference contains the entire URL-path (captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, not the *CondPattern*). You could simply remove `forums/` from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*, however, the preceding *condition* that checks against `REQUEST_URI` is not required and this could be tidied.

Try the following instead, at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(forums/.*) https://new-domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

There is no need for the additional condition as the URL-path can be matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead (more efficient).

The `$1` backreference contains the entire URL-path, that starts with `forums/`.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect - only change it to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache, since any erroneous 301s are likely to have been cached.